# How to find duplicates from List of objects, how to find if in objects duplicate names have against one id

Tags: javascript, java, arraylist

Example :

emp-1  : {id:1,name:A}

emp-2  : {id:1,name:B}

emp-3  : {id:2,name:B}

emp-2  : {id:1,name:A}

```
List<emps>
```

How to find duplicate `name` by using `id`

my sample code if possible tune this to best

```
Map<Long, List<String>> dulicateNamesById = new HashMap<>();
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
for (Emp emp: emps) {
  if (dulicateNamesById.containsKey(emp.getId())) {
    List<String> list = dulicateNamesById.get(emp.getId());
    if(list.contains(emp.getName())){
      return "XXXXXXX"; // if duplicate name present aganest same id return message
    }
    values.add(emp.getName());
    dulicateNamesById.put(emp.getId(), values);
  } else {
      values = new ArrayList<>();
      values.add(emp.getName());
      dulicateNamesById.put(emp.getId(), values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the same regardless of language: Iterate the list and look for duplicates. There are many ways to do this, one of which is to add the names to a new list, `newList`, and throw an exception if `newList` already contains the name.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple solution for deleting a duplicate key

```
var arrayWithDuplicates = [
{"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "12345", state:"NV"},
{"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "A7846", state:"CA"},
{"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "12345", state:"OR"},
{"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "10849", state:"CA"},
{"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "B7037", state:"WA"},
{"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "12345", state:"NM"}
];

function removeDuplicates(originalArray, prop) {
 var newArray = [];
 var lookupObject  = {};

 for(var i in originalArray) {
    lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]] = originalArray[i];
 }

 for(i in lookupObject) {
     newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
 }
  return newArray;


}

var uniqueArray = removeDuplicates(arrayWithDuplicates, "licenseNum");
console.log(uniqueArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the included class, the following reports duplicates based on id. It simply groups ever one who has the same ID in the same `set`.

```
        List<Emp> emps = List.of(new Emp(1, "A"), new Emp(1, "B"),
                new Emp(2, "B"), new Emp(1, "A"));
        Map<Integer, List<Emp>> dups = emps.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy((Emp e) -> e.id));

        dups.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

> 1=[(1, A), (1, B)] 
>   2=[(2, B)]

```
class Emp {
    public int id;
    public String name;

    public Emp(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Integer.hashCode(id);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       return ((Emp)obj).id == id;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + id + ", " + name+ ")";
    }

}
```